# tikz matrix, newcommand

Tags: macros, tikz-matrix

Is it possible to use "\newcommand" with a TikZ-matrix ?

This code doesn't work...

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}


\newcommand \toto{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes]
{
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\toto

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please, don't use `minimal` for examples. It's not meant for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you replace the `&`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\toto}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
2 \& 2 \& 2 \& 2 \& 4 \& 2 \& 4 \& 2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\toto

\end{document}
```